# Java vs Objective-C : Exception, reaching of finally block

Tags: java, objective-c, exception, finally

I test exceptions using in java an dobjective-C programs.

In these tests, I see a difference in the way of finally block is reached when an exception is catched and rethrown.

Here my java test :

```
    try {
        Boolean bThrow = true;
        System.out.println("try : before exception sent");
        if (bThrow) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        System.out.println("try : after sent");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch, rethrow");
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally");
    }
```

which displays :

```
try: before exception sent
catch, rethrow
finally
```

And here my objective-c test :

```
    @try {
        NSException *myexc = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"exceptionTest" reason:@"exceptionTest" userInfo:nil];
        BOOL bThrow = YES;
        NSLog(@"try : before exception sent");
        if (bThrow) {
            @throw myexc;
        }
        NSLog(@"try : after sent");
    }
    @catch (Exception *exception) {
        NSLog(@"catch, rethrow");
        @throw exception;
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"finally");
    }
```

which displays :

```
try: before exception sent
catch, rethrown
*** Terminating app
```

**Code in finally block is not reached !**

Why this difference ?

[EDIT] Sorry, @try ... @try ... @try... was a mistake.
I changed it, but the problem is the same, i can't reach finally block in objective-c test

Comment: Because they are different languages???

Comment: I see no finally keyword in your Obj-C example.

Comment: Why is the ObjC version doing try, try and try?

Comment: You should use `@catch` and `@finally` in objective-c, not always `@try`!

Comment: What makes you think that they should execute the same when they're not coded equivalently?

Comment: @SJuan76 and EJP Yes it's different languages, but they both use exception mechanism which should be used equivalently whatever the language. I ask here if you know the reason of this difference

Comment: If you are trying to recover from exceptions in Objective-C, then **you are doing it wrong**.

Comment: @bbum I don't understand, what do you mean with "recover from exceptions" ?

Comment: If you are using @catch to do anything but report an error and kill your app, you are doing it wrong.  Objective-c does not use exceptions for flow control or to indicate user validation errors a la Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, i solved my problem.

In my objective-c test, application crashed, that's why finally block was not reached.

If I add a try catch block in the main, now in my function, finally block is reached !

So, I confirm that finally block is still reached whatever an excpetion occurs (and is rethrown) or not).

Answer (score 4):

Your Objective-C code does not have a finally block, just three try blocks.  It should look like this:

```
@try {
    NSException *myexc = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"exceptionTest" reason:@"exceptionTest" userInfo:nil];
    BOOL bThrow = YES; // Use BOOL or bool
    NSLog(@"try : before exception sent");
    if (bThrow) {
        @throw myexc;
    }
    NSLog(@"try : after sent");
}
@catch (NSException *e) {  // use catch not another try
    NSLog(@"catch, rethrow");
    @throw e;
}
@finally {                 // use finally not another try
    NSLog(@"finally");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in copy code. I changed it in my first post. But it still don't reach finally block